# Labels clipping with canvas in ggplot2 polar coordinate

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart in polar coordinates in ggplot2, but am having issues with text getting cut off when the plot is saved.

Most of what I've tried has been in the `ggsave()` statement, adjusting height, width, and scale parameters

Creating the data for the plot:

```
testData <- data.frame(Biome = c(rep('Rainforest', 3), rep('Temperate Forest', 1), rep('Desert', 2), rep('Grassland', 1), rep('Estuary', 3)),
                       Threat = c(3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1))
```

Creating the plot:

```
test_plot <- ggplot(testData, aes(x = Biome, y = as.character(Threat), group = Threat, fill = as.character(Threat))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', width = 0.95, colour = 'black', size = 2) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = 'red', '2' = 'darkorange', '3' = 'darkgreen'), labels = c('High', 'Medium', 'Low')) +
  labs(fill = 'Ecosystem Threat') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'white', face = 'bold'),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(colour = 'white', face = 'bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = 'white', face = 'bold'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'black', colour = NA))
```

Saving the plot:

```
ggsave('~Path~To~Plot',  test_plot , dpi = 1200, bg = 'transparent', height = 3, width = 7, units = 'in')
```

Currently, the plot looks fine in the RStudio plot viewer, but when saved some of the text on the labels (which are really axis text) are cut off by the bounds of the canvas ("Rainforest" on the left, "Estuary" on the right):

[image: Plot]

Comment: Have you considered replacing your `coord_polar()` with `coord_polar(clip = "off")`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't tried that before posting this question. I just did, but with no success.

Comment: I too ran your code, but the .png seems fine when using the `clip = "off"`.